# Concating two arrays results in nested array when one is constructed via map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary, concatenation

I am trying to concat two arrays using the concat-method.

However, if one of them if constructed using jQuery's "map" method, I receive a nested array:

```
var first = [];
var second = $("").map(function (e, i) { return null; }); ;

var result = first.concat(second);
alert(result.length);
alert(result[0]);
```

The output of the alerts are "1" respectively "[object Object]" while I would expect "0" and "undefined".
The debugger shows that result is "[ [ ] ]".

What's wrong here?
The [documentation clearly states](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) that map returns an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are linking to the wrong method. Here is the method you are using:

http://api.jquery.com/map/

It return a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks. I just needed to add a call to jQuery.makeArray() to fix it.